# What is the message given?

Tags: word, wordplay

A friend of mine had an important message for me. Can you also read this important message below?

```
Fr s tH pTh t tH dRk sD Fr lDs t ngr Ngr ldS t hT Ht lDs t sffRng
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's

> “Fear is the path to the dark side. Fear leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering.” a famous quote from Yoda of Star Wars

Just skimming the letters I could see it

Comment: It seems like his friend is now his enemy... :D :p

Comment: faster than I expected :D and @manshu no, he is still a friend of mine, or my previous self as shown in the RotJ